# Assign deciles to distribution

Tags: r, assign, quantile

I need to assign deciles to a distribution but in the form of integers.
Like 1 should correspond to the first decile, 2 to the second, 3 to the third...
at the moment I'm using the following code that does not do exactly what I am looking for.

```
cut(x, breaks = quantile(data, probs = seq(0, 1, 0.1)))
```

So, instead of this type of result:

```
(0,100] (100,200]
```

I would like to have something like:

```
1   90
2   130
2   150
3   230
```

Does anyone already have some code for this?

Comment: use the `labels` argument in `cut`

Comment: Perfect Thank you :)

Comment: @RichardTelford post as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `labels` argument in `cut`

```
x2 <- cut(x, breaks = quantile(x, probs = seq(0, 1, 0.1)), 
  labels = 1:10, include.lowest = TRUE)
```

This will return a factor. Run

```
as.numeric(as.character(x2))
```

to convert this to an integer (yes, I know in this particular case the as.character is redundant).

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with a `data.frame.`, you can do this:

```
df$decile <- cut(df$x, breaks= quantile(df$x, probs= seq(0, 1, by= 0.1)), 
            include.lowest= TRUE, 
            labels= c(1:10))
```

in case you want to use a `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, decile := cut(x, breaks= quantile(x, probs= seq(0, 1, by= 0.1)), 
                          include.lowest= TRUE, 
                          labels= c(1:10)) ]
```